DevExpress Report Using Unbound Data
Using VB.NET & Visual Studio 2022
I have a form with misc fields and unbound data and variable.
I am not using a database. Its just a small project.
How do I send the unbound data to an xtraReport1 report?
I have looked all through DevExpress site to find out how, but all I can find is how to hook up a data source using a database or json file

I accidently figured it out.
I can pass a variable or any data directly to the report.
The "txt1" is a variable I pass from main form to report
I use this code on the XtrReport1.vb form designer
Public Sub New()
    
   ' This call is required by the designer.
   InitializeComponent()
    
   ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
   XrLabel1.Text = txt1
    
End Sub

